# Scaling Issue for Bar Graph in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, height, border, scale

I'm trying to create a bar graph with HTML/CSS and I'm having trouble with CSS's `scale` property. Here's my code so far:

```css
    .main {
      position: absolute;
      top: 350px;
      width: 80%;
      height: 65%;
      background-color: #1d1d1d;
      border: 20px #3f3f3f solid;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    }
    
    .bar {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 30px;
      margin-left: 1.1%;
      background-color: #38ff90;
      border-top: 5px #1d6d41 solid;
      border-left: 5px #1d6d41 solid;
      border-right: 5px #1d6d41 solid;
      transform-origin: bottom;
      transform: scaleY(10);
    }
    
    .bar-height {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="main">
        <div style="height: 100%;" class="bar-height"></div>
        <div style="height: <?php echo $height ?>px;" class="bar">         </div>
    </div>
```

When I use `scale()`, this ends up scaling the `border` on each `bar`. How can I scale the `bar` element without scaling the `border`?

Comment: first of all we can't see which height is echoed by your php, moreover when i run a snippet of your code, just nothing happens (there's no content, colors etc to see what's happening and how to help you). Please, add values and something that can be displayed, use fixed values, then you'll only have to change it for your php variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've some examples here:

note that it's usually done with SCSS or JS /any JS framework.

https://codepen.io/Victa/pen/xDqbf

https://codepen.io/dxdc100xp/pen/WwMQwE

https://codepen.io/baletsa/pen/oHcfr

the `code` provided is only to see the logic and the procedure for reach this. SCSS is a good option and not too difficult to use it's like CSS on steroids.